# Building a formula builder for the end user in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have to build a formula builder in javascript rather knockoutjs.

The way I have thought about this.. have a div on the left side of web page which has list of formula(eg. concat, lcase, etc..) and have another div on right side of page having list of variables.

And in the middle pane have the formula builder..

I tried to search for something similar in open source but was unable to find any..

I should be able to build the list of formulas and variables on the web page using knockoutjs but after that I have no clue how to go forward..

I was thinking on these lines.. The formula names on the left and variable names on the right would be clickable and when clicked on will show itself on the middle pane. So if clicked on concat it would show 'concat( , )' but lcase would show lcase( ). When the cursor was brought in the empty space and a variable name was clicked the formula would get created.

So these are what I would like to understand.

a)What should I have in the middle pane? A div or a text box. I would not want users to be able to type anything but they must be able to take the cursor on the area and select where they want the formula name or variable name to come up.

b)I would appreciate if someone could help me with the method which would enable clicking on the formula names and variable names and bring them on the middle pane as well as create the observable to return.

Any help is sincerely appreciated..
Thanks and warm regards
Arnab

Comment: Hmmm, I think you need a peer, sparring partner, product owner, or other form of extended source of feedback. Afraid your question as is will be too broad for SO.

Comment: The middle pane should have a `<span>` for each location that can be clicked. Other than that, start writing code, and ask a question when you run into something you can't figure out.

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks for the suggestion of using <span>, but how do I show it this way.. for eg.. in case of formula concat, I can have a js object  {text:concat. value:concat( , )}, so when one clicks on concat, the value concat ( , ) comes in middle pane.. now how to add the <span>..  I will check if making the value:concat(<span></span> ,<span></span> ) works, any pointers?? Tx again..

Comment: You will probably have a template in the middle pane, and clicking on the formula name would change the template. It's really more than one question to write your program. Just start coding it up as well as you can and ask a new question when you run into a road block.